# Align text vertically on center

Tags: inkscape, text

I'm using inkscape and I want to put a text vertically on center, the following text has a two font sizes, i want to display them on baseline.

I can't convert text to path because I put on path.
[image]

Comment: You may want to look into type tools that allow you to create a baseline shift and apply those to the plus sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the "+" selected use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to adjust the positioning of the glyph.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> will "shift" vertically as you want to do. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> will adjust the kerning.

Reference: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Formatting.html